# How can I update object in object?

Tags: javascript

I have a function:

```
function updateStorage(result) {
    const dataFromStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('links'))

    const index = dataFromStorage.findIndex(d => d.id === result.id)
    dataFromStorage[index] = Object.assign({}, dataFromStorage[index], result)

    localStorage.setItem('links', JSON.stringify(dataFromStorage))
}
```

And when I try to update object and object in object I rewrite nested object but I want to update

```
var result = {
    id: id,
    PageSpeedInsights: {
        [preloaderType]: false,
        [errorStatus]: false,
        [type]: +(lighthouse.categories.performance['score'] * 100).toFixed()
    }
}
updateStorage(result)
```

Before function:

[image]

After function:

[image]

How can I fix my function?

Comment: why you need the {} in Object.assign? look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in an update function:

```
  function updateStorage(id, update) {
    store(id, update(get(id)); // fill in your logic here
  }
```

That could then be used as:

```
 updateStorage(id, prev => ({ ...prev, PageSpeedInsights: { ...prev.PageSpeedInsights, /*update*/ } }));
```

Comment: sorry, but your function is not universal. My function update data not only nested (PageSpeedInsights)